# Disallowing Users of a Custom Role from Deleting or Adding Administrators?

Tags: users, capabilities, user-roles, user-access

*(**Moderator's note:** The original title was "Custom User Role Restrictions")*

A project I am working on requires me to create two new user roles - one for the owner of the website and the other for agents of the company.

With the website owner user role I was just looking for a way to restrict users in this group from modifying core site settings while having access to modify all other settings.

The code below seems to work perfectly for everything other than the user management area. I did want users of this group to be able to add/modify website users BUT where I am running into a problem is that users of this group currently have the ability to create users in the *"Administrator"* category and they are also able to deleting existing *"Administrators"*.

What I am looking for is a way to modify the code below so that such users can NOT delete or modify a user account which is set as *"Administrator"* and restrict the user from being able to create a new Administrator account.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

```
// CREATE CUSTOM - SITE OWNER - USER ROLE WITH CUSTOM CAPABILITIES
if (!get_role('website_owner')) {
  //let's use the editor as the base capabilities
  $caps = get_role('editor')->capabilities; 
  $caps = array_merge( $caps, array(
    'install_plugins'               => false,
    'activate_plugins'              => false,
    'update_plugins'                => false,
    'delete_plugins'                => false,
    'list_users'                    => true,
    'add_users'                     => true,
    'create_users'                  => true,
    'edit_users'                    => true,
    'delete_users'                  => true,
    'remove_users'                  => true,
    'unfiltered_upload'             => true,
    'install_themes'                => false,
    'update_themes'                 => false,
    'delete_themes'                 => false,
    'switch_themes'                 => false,
    'edit_theme_options'            => true,
    'manage_options'                => false,
    'import'                        => false,
    'update_core'                   => false,
    'edit_dashboard'                => false,
    'gravityforms_view_entries'     => true,
    'gravityforms_edit_entries'     => true,
    'gravityforms_delete_entries'   => true,
    'gravityforms_export_entries'   => true,
    'gravityforms_view_entry_notes' => true,
    'gravityforms_edit_entry_notes' => true,
    'gravityforms_feed'             => true,
  )); //adding new capabilities.
  // Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table
  add_role( 'website_owner', 'Website Owner', $caps );
}
```

Comment: I've never done any customization of user roles, nor do I think this is going to help your problem, but you have an extra comma at the end of your array. The comma on 'gravityforms_feed' => true," shouldn't be there.

Comment: @eileen: extra comma at the end of array is acceptable by php

Comment: @eileen.carpenter - Props to *@silent*, I almost always include a trailing comma on my arrays in PHP. The extra comma is, in my book, a best practice and one of the things the designers of PHP really got right. Why? Because it makes it easy to add a line via copy & paste without introducing a syntax error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi **@NetConstructor:**

I think this is what you need. Note that I didn't include the full setup of your `'website_owner'` role, just the addition of a new capability called `'manage_administrators'`.

Also, I only attempted to remove the *"Delete"* link from any users that don't have the `'manage_administrators'` capability *(which you'll need to add to the administrator role, of course)* and I also simply removed the *Administrator* as a role option on the *"Add New User"* page. I didn't attempt to ensure they can't delete or add administrators via some nefarious method, and I didn't disable any other feature that might allow them to add or delete administrators. That said, maybe this is sufficient?

```
add_action('user_row_actions','yoursite_user_row_actions',10,2);
function yoursite_user_row_actions($actions, $user_object) {  // remove the ability to delete an administrator
  global $pagenow;
  if ($pagenow=='users.php' && isset($user_object->caps['administrator']) && !current_user_can('manage_administrators'))
    unset($actions['edit']);
    unset($actions['delete']);
  return $actions;
}
add_action('editable_roles','yoursite_editable_roles');
function yoursite_editable_roles($all_roles) { // remove the ability to add an administrator
  global $pagenow;
if (in_array($pagenow,array('user-edit.php','user-new.php')) &&           
       !current_user_can('manage_administrators'))
    unset($all_roles['administrator']);
  return $all_roles;
}
add_action('admin_init','yoursite_admin_init');
function yoursite_admin_init() {
  $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
  $wp_roles->use_db = true;
  $administrator = $wp_roles->get_role('administrator');
  if (!$administrator->has_cap('manage_administrators'))
    $wp_roles->add_cap('administrator','manage_administrators');

  $website_owner = $wp_roles->get_role('website_owner');
  if (!$website_owner) {
    //let's use the editor as the base capabilities
    $caps = get_role('editor')->capabilities;
    $caps = array_merge( $caps, array(
      'install_plugins'               => false,
      'activate_plugins'              => false,
      'update_plugins'                => false,
      'delete_plugins'                => false,
      'list_users'                    => true,
      'add_users'                     => true,
      'create_users'                  => true,
      'edit_users'                    => true,
      'delete_users'                  => true,
      'remove_users'                  => true,
      'unfiltered_upload'             => true,
      'install_themes'                => false,
      'update_themes'                 => false,
      'delete_themes'                 => false,
      'switch_themes'                 => false,
      'edit_theme_options'            => true,
      'manage_options'                => false,
      'import'                        => false,
      'update_core'                   => false,
      'edit_dashboard'                => false,
      'gravityforms_view_entries'     => true,
      'gravityforms_edit_entries'     => true,
      'gravityforms_delete_entries'   => true,
      'gravityforms_export_entries'   => true,
      'gravityforms_view_entry_notes' => true,
      'gravityforms_edit_entry_notes' => true,
      'gravityforms_feed'             => true,
      'manage_administrators'         => false,
    ));
    $wp_roles->add_role('website_owner','Website Owner',$caps);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Mike -- has Mike, thanks for this... Can I assume that once this is added to my functions file that I just have to add 'manage_administrators' => true, to the code I posted above?

Comment: @Mike -- Sorry I meant to define it as false above. Also, when I add your code and add the 'manage_administrators' => false, to my custom role then when I go to add a new user the "role" dropdown form field is blank.

Comment: @NetConstructor.com - Weeelll... that's what I get for providing code I didn't fully test. Sheesh, on my part!  The code's updated and I *think* it is now fully tested. FYI, the error was a copy/paste error where `yoursite_editable_roles()` was returning `$action` instead of `$all_roles`. I also tried to make the `init` hook fully workable so that hopefully anyone would be able to copy and paste this code into their theme's `functions.php` file to see it work.

Comment: @Mike -- Thanks Mike but something must be wrong with this. I went ahead and deleted my code (which I originally posted in the question) and replaced it with the complete code you just posted. I then went to add a new user account and assign the "website owner" role and logged in with that account. When I access the user management area from that account I am still able to see the "Website Owner" and "Administrator" roles in the dropdown when viewing/editing a user account and I am able to select either of those and save the data. I think its not working... does it work for you?

Comment: @NetConstructor.com - But you didn't say anything about viewing or editing, you only said adding! ;-) I've changed the `if` statement in `yoursite_editable_roles()` to filter for `'user-edit.php'` too. There may be other cases where it doesn't work as you are anticipating I haven't tried to make sure it handles everything; that's like verifying that there is not a needle in that haystack and is a lot more like my client work. :) Can you understand what the code is doing so you can track down any other potential contexts that the code might need to be adapted to fix?

Comment: @NetConstructor - I also just added code to remove the *"Edit"* link from administrators when not able to manage administrators.

Comment: @Mike -- I am not sure what the problem is here but I honestly don't see any difference at all in the admin areas between the original code I posted and replacing it with the code you provides/updated so kindly. I do remember wordpress can be kinda tricky when you modify an existing role with new capabilities so I am thinking the problem might be related to needing to clear the capabilities of "website_owner" first before a new user can be created under the role. Do you know how to clear the capabilities correctly? (I screwed up my wp install once by doing it incorrectly)

Comment: @Mike -- Oh, one more thing... The other areas that I could think of which might be related here are the "drop down" on the user list admin page so that website_owners can't delete administrators or users with a higher function than them (same for bulk actions) and not being able use the bulk "change role" options... not sure if you took that into account by chance. Sorry btw, I should have been more clear in my description regarding your previous comment :-)

Comment: @NetConstructor.com - It's really hard to diagnose your specific situation from afar. I'm confident the code works on a clean install, and me figuring it out abstractly will be a lot harder than you figuring it out given you have the system in your hands. At this point it sounds like you probably need to try on a freshly installed installation?

Comment: @Mike -- I just confirmed that the assumption I made in the last comment was indeed correct. Explanation: I was not able to modify the existing capability on the custom role I had already created from the code I posted initially. Capabilities seem to be saved in the db the first time the code is run. I confirmed this by replacing "website_owner" to "website_admin" then assigning the new role. Once I did this everything worked BUT the previous capability was still in the dropdown although no users had that capability assigned and no code referenced it. As such do you know how to clean the file?

Comment: @Mike -- I noticed only two small issues with the code. 1st) a user with this newly assigned capability can still access a user with the "Administrator" role and on the detail page for that user he is able to change his capability to a lesser role than Administrator. If the user has a higher capability the dropdown option should not be available. On the post list screen it is not possible to assign a the user to a different capability which is good. On the user list page it is also possible for the role to select users with a higher role and delete them. Other than that its perfect I think.

Comment: @NetConstructor.com - I don't want to be harsh but I am sensing a pattern from this and a few prior questions. The goal of an answer (for me) is to empower the question asker to solve their own issues which I do for challenge, learning and to help others. I don't answer to initiate an ongoing series of questions to handhold through every subsequent detail; that feels a lot like consulting and becomes very stressful for me. If you are struggling with follow ups to answers posted here maybe you should subcontract out these issues? I could help but others here or elsewhere could help too.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe this is now meant to be done using [`map_meta_cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/map_meta_cap) :

*For example to block deleting or editing the admin user who has an id of 1 you would do this:*

```
add_filter('map_meta_cap', function( $required_caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ){

   $protected_user = 1; // ID of admin user you want to block from being edited

    if ( $user_id === $protected_user ) // Don't block caps if current user = protected user
        return $required_caps;
    $blocked_caps = array(
        'delete_user',
        'edit_user',
        'remove_user'
        );
    if ( in_array( $cap, $blocked_caps ) && $args[0] === $protected_user )
        $required_caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
    return $required_caps;
}, 10, 4 );
```

**You can add any additional capabilities that you want blocked to the `$blocked_caps` array.**

I also add this in for hiding myself from the `wp-admin/users.php` page. It would probably be better unsetting the user with php, but it doesn't really make a different since the admin can't be edited anyway if you are using the above function.

```
function hide_admin_user_bw() {
  ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    .users-php tr#user-1 {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .users-php li.administrator {
        display: none!important;
    }
    </style>
  <?php
}
add_action('admin_head-users.php', 'hide_admin_user_bw');
```

Comment: The way you protect user id 1 is really good. Thank you. We want to use your method to hide an admin for a client. The only issue I find is that when I (as another admin) directly try to access profile id 1, I get the message:  `Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this user`, which is a dead giveaway that the user does exist. It would be nice if (you could alter your code) so one would get `Invalid user ID` which is the returned message for a non-existing user. What do you think?